# Confused by time signatures

Tags: time-signatures

I know people ask about time signatures often, and I've read some of the posts, and haven't seen an answer to what confuses me.

I know that :
4/4 means 4 quarter notes.
3/4 means 4 quarter notes.

So here's what confused me: in the second example, what are they a quarter of? They're not a quarter of the measure, they're a 3rd of the measure.

You can't fill something up with 3 quarters, that would leave part of it empty. But you can fill it up with 3 quarters of something else, but I have a hard time grasping what it's quarters of.

Is it "3 elements of what would be quarter notes if it was in 4/4"? So is 4/4 like the benchmark and are the other time signatures depicted relative to that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just too trivial

Comment: This is not a bad question at all!

Comment: Please, please explain why you need to regard all this in the way that's becoming apparent in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology has tripped you - and loads of others, up! The longest note is/was a *breve*, which represented a whole bar. Somehow, it turned out it was too long, so common time, 4/4, was born, using a *semibreve* as the note to fill the bar completely.

So, four *one beat* notes are equivalent to that semibreve, and are often called *crotchets*. Every time the time signature shows 4/4, it will mean there are 4 crotchets per bar. These, then can be called *quarter* notes. When the time sig. is 3/4, aka *three-quarter time*, there will only be 3 one beat/crotchet notes in each bar. Each bar is still considered full - as it's known as three-quarter time - each bar is only three quarters as long as the 'standard' bar (4/4), also called *common time*.

Put a slightly different way - the bottom number tells what sort of notes, the top number tells how many per bar - very similar to a fraction in maths. Hope this clears up what is a potentially confusing part of written music.

Comment: The naming system of “quarters”, “half”, etc appear to be a curiously North American enterprise. International friends have over the years pointed out how silly the naming system is. Indeed it gets much worse when rhythms become more difficult (e.g. triplet-quarters / quintuplet-eighths; why not “sixth” or “tenth notes”?) In this respect, both naming systems could use some help, though admittedly the European system is a bit clearer for general use / knowledge.

Comment: Deprecating "quarter" , "eighth", etc.  on such basis is hyperpedantic IMHO.  It's certainly much easier to write, say, and identify written note forms using the 1/(2^n) system than that curiously British collection of random names.   Further,  the beat length of a written eighth note depends on other factors (triplets, etc.) as jjmusicnotes points out.    Just count the flags and you can calculate the note-name; something much more difficult if you insist on calling it a hemisemidemimicronanoattoquaver.

Comment: Thanks for your usual style of comment. Didn't deprecate (although something similar did cross my mind). In reality, this question would never have been posed if the 'proper' names were known and used. Tuplets weren't coming into the equation, and are - or should be - clearly noted - or notated. There's a slight hint at racism in the comment, which might just get it deleted...!  Why not try your hand at more answering and less commenting? Seriously.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. It mentions that 4/4 has the standard bar (and is called common time), which does seem to be the case and is vital to understanding this properly. In 4/4, a quarter note would be 60 / bpm, and regardless of the time signature, this is used as the benchmark.

Comment: Thanks, but do not get bpm into the equation, as it has little to do with the time signature - believe me!

Comment: It has everything to do with it in my case. The whole reason why I'm trying to understand time signatures is so I can calculate durations of bars, which you can't without bpm.
But also, more generally speaking, all answers say something to the extent of "it's a quarter of a whole note". To define that whole note, BPM does come into the equation. The whole note is (240 / bpm), at least from my current understanding.

Comment: @SvenM , no a whole note, like all the other notes, have nothing to do with bpm until you've defined which note gets a beat.

Comment: Tim,  all the same, if you see a time signature of  6/8, do you really read it as "six slash semidemibreve" (or whatever an eighth note is)?   Fractions of a whole note are fundamental to the time signature; why break away from that elsewhere?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I do think my math is sound, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong... Say we are in 7/8 at 120 bpm. Each bar would last (240 / bpm / 8 * 7) =  (240 / 120 / 8  * 7) = 1.75, which is exactly what my DAW tells me too. Seems to work for every BPM and time signature... I don't know how to set "which note gets the beat" besides setting the time signature though.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : so using that formula for 3/4, we'd get (240 / bpm / 4 * 3) per bar, indicating that there are "3 units of a quarter of (240/bpm)" in a bar. And if a quarter is (240/bpm), a whole is (240/bpm).

Comment: Sorry, meant to say,”if a quarter is a quarter of (240/bpm) at the end there.

Comment: @SvenM please **Please** stop bringing beats per minute into this.  It has nothing at all to do with relative note length or the notation thereof

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How else would you determine the actual duration of a bar, if you can't use BPM? As far as I know there's two factors needed, time sigature and bpm. The math seems to work, at least from the 10 tests I've done (with different bpms and signatures). Can you show me an example when a whole note is not 240 divided by bpm?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : The question I asked comes down to "a quarter of what". You can keep this theoretic and only relative to other notes, in which case it's "it's a quarter of a whole note"... but a valid answer would also be how long it takes in actual time, and for that, the variable BPM comes into the equation. As far as I know, my formula works for that (which I derived from the more theoretical answers given). There could be caveats that I'm not aware of yet though.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I merely think 6 quavers, as that is what makes up a 6/8 bar basically. 6 eighth notes works, but it must come down to personal preference and habit.

Comment: @SvenM - in my experience - and that of most musicians, bars are not timed as to how many seconds/milliseconds they take to play. Bpm is a guide, and generally in simple time, a beat is defined as the bottom number in a time sig. How many will be played in one minute. Hence 'beats per minute'. This is often then checked using a metronome. Once a *pulse* has been established, the piece is played feeling that pulse. What we *don't* do is time each bar like it seems you want to.   We don't understand why you want to count like this. Help!!

Comment: @Tim : I'm making a music tool that needs to find durations of segments based on time signature, BPM and number of bars. So it was key to understand how time signatures work, and then take it one step further and know how this relates to BPM. I got the understanding part down based on the answers here, and based on that I figured out the calculations for the extra step, and figured I would share that information as it's hard to find, and others might find it useful, and if it was inaccurate, maybe someone could correct it. It wasn't off topic either, as it's an answer to the question too.

Comment: Now it makes sense! Except - that for a lot of music - probably electronic/dance not included - the beat is not as stable as it appears. There's a fair bit of 'push and pull' going on, so it may or may not be as useful as you might hope for. Even tracks which appear to be spot on, on the tempo, will and do fluctuate.  Basically, unless the track was recorded with strict adherence to tempo using a click track, the idea will produce flaws. Good luck, though !

Answer (score 5):

> what are they a quarter of?

A whole note. It's all very self-referential.

There exists a type of note called a *whole note*. It takes up some amount of time, to be determined by the time signature and tempo. Whatever a whole note ends up being, a *half note* is half of it, a *quarter note* is a quarter of it (and half of a half note), etc.

4/4 is a time signature where there are four beats per measure, and each beat is represented by a quarter note. The measure can be filled with a single whole note, two half notes, four quarters, or any combination that adds up correctly.

3/4 is a time signature where there are three beats per measure, and each beat is represented by a quarter note. A whole note is too large to fit in a 3/4 measure.

Comment: The really daft thing is - that 'whole note' is called a semibreve (in backward England...) which in itself is actually half of something - a breve! So, technically, it could make more sense - to beginners - to call a 'crotchet' an eighth note...

Comment: And really much dafter - 'breve' translates as 'short'...

Comment: Since this is a question caused by confusing terminology, I was very careful to keep my terminology as clear as possible. The British names are irrelevant here and just make things worse.

Comment: Understood. Just pointing out how ludicrous the whole thing can appear. The English names are very clear, and equivocal, however.

Comment: In regards to what that "some amount of time" mentioned is :
After doing some experimentation in a DAW, it turns out that at 60 bpm, a quarter note is always 1 second regardless of time signature, and a whole note is 4 seconds. So it looks like a whole note is always equal to 240 / bpm, regardless of time signature.
And a quarter note is always 60 / bpm, and an eight is 30 / bpm.
So in 3/4, that means 3 units of (60 / bpm), and in 6/8, that means 6 units of (30 / bpm).

Comment: I think it's a mistake to try to think about things in terms of absolute length of time. Embrace the relativeness of the system.

Comment: @SvenM - no, no, no. This is not a good way to think about time signatures. The research does not mean that a quarter note (crotchet) is ALWAYS 60 bpm, only when it ACTUALLY IS 60bpm.

Comment: @Tim : you misunderstood me. I said "at 60 bpm, it's always"... and then later I said 60 / bpm. This works for any BPM. Say 120 bpm, that would be 60 / 120, which is half a second.

Comment: @SvenM, I can see that an investigation of tempo (BPM) is helping you assimilate the concept of beats and note values, but it may be over complicating things when it comes to time signatures such as 3/2. Yes there is a nexus between time signature and tempo, but it is simpler to treat them separately, that is: understand the time signature and then assign a tempo (BPM). Incidentally, in Australia we like it both ways and commonly use semibreve, minim, crotchet, quaver and semiquaver, avoid the term 'quarter note' but use sixteenths and thirty seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case appears to be nomenclature more than anything else. In other parts of the world a ‘quarter note’ is called a crochet.

A half note is called a minim. 
A whole note is called a semi-breve 
And a note with double the value of a semi breve is called a breve.

In my country we learn both and it might benefit you to do so as well.

A quarter note is a quarter of a semi-breve which is itself half of a much longer archaic note value.

I teach my students to say ‘4 crochet beets per bar’. Or ‘4 quarter note beats bee bar’.

I eve distinguish between crochets and crotches beats since a bar might just have a dotted minim (half note) or something else with the suivaient value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Giving it another name could help with seeing it differently, but I'm still confused.
In 3/4, does a mimim last 2 crochets as well, and a semi-breve 4 crochets? So that's "one bar and one crochet"?

Comment: A quarter note is just a bad name. It is a quarter of something but not the measure itself. It is a quarter of a note four times as long as it is. Which is self evident but not all that useful when you think about it.